# How do I make this sentence sound better?

Tags: word-usage

"They both agree that Athens wields and uses her power mistakenly."

They is Plato and Thucydides.

Athens is her.

Athens is the one that uses the power mistakenly.

I just wonder if there should be a different word used for "mistakenly."

Comment: You could sing it to the tune of *The Battle Hymn of the Republic*.  That might help.  Seriously though, you need to provide more information.  What do you think is wrong with this sentence?  How do you want it to be improved?  What would make it better, in your opinion?

Comment: Well, let us know who _she_ is, for starts. Is she _Athens_? Could be. But maybe not. And who are _they_? Pronouns without referents don't sound good. And _wield_ is a very fancy word that occurs in fantasy games and novels, but isn't really used in normal English. Also, it's not clear what _mistakenly_ refers to. Who's mistaken? _Her? Athens? They?_ someone else? only one of _they_? And what is the mistake? It's just unclear.

Comment: It's not clear what you think is wrong with *mistakenly*. Perhaps you are thinking of something like *incorrectly*? Or even *in error*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be requesting proofreading or perhaps copyediting.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions...

- use antecedents for pronoun (they) or remove it. (*"John and Mary both... / Both agree..."*)
- replace *agree* with a stronger verb
- *wields... mistakenly* is an uncommon adverb pair, I am guessing. Look for a more specific modifier (*"carelessly", "crudely", "foolishly"*, etc.)

Just variants. "Better" is not a clear figure of merit with soft arts like language. Except for maybe the 3rd point, which you might be able to demonstrate with a corpus ngram

Answer (score 1):

**They both agree that Athens wields and uses her power mistakenly.**

Note I answered this question before it was edited.

First, I assume Athens references the city state of Athens. Secondly you have used the female form for the city I have seen this done numerous times in Historical texts/stories but it is not necessary. Thirdly presumably we Know who "they" are. Hence we can remove Both from the sentence. Finally as I have no context I am unsure of the tense to be used. It sounds possible we are talking about something that has already happened.

**They agree(d) that the power and influence of Athens is(was) misused.**

> **misuse** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misuse?q=misused)
>   noun/verb  to use something in an **unsuitable way** or in a way **that was not intended:**
>
> Example There were suggestions that the articles involved the misuse of historical concepts and their evidence was wrong.

Comment: Do you think this could work:                                                                                     They agreed that the power and the influence of Athens power was misused.

Comment: there is no need to repeat power

Comment: But the way u said it makes it sound like Athens' influence. But I only wan't to talk about there power

Comment: They agree(d) that  Athens  misused its power.

Comment: thanks for the clarification